# How to use a different .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I got the common .bashrc in my /home/ folder. But I have another .basrch (.bashrc1) (I have a lot of aliases) I cannot copy the content from one to another. So. I want to know if there is a possibility to use the .bashrc1 as default or if there is an additional command to execute the aliases that are into the .bashrc1

Thanks

Comment: .bashrc belongs to `/home/user`. I'm guessing you meant that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.bashrc`, put

```
source /path/to/.bashrc1
```

To force bash to use a different `.bashrc` (bad practice)

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/Bob/
bash --rcfile ~/Bob/.bashrc
```

For example, if you use GNOME, add a custom keyboard shortcut with above command.

Comment: But there is a command to adjunst the .bashrc1 as default? Or everytime that I want to use a new .bashrc I have to source on it?

Comment: @NicolasSantisteban I added that as well.

Comment: You can also symlink bashrc to another file.

Comment: @User112638726 OP says he cannot copy. He needs to keep separate copies.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 You wouldn't need to copy anything, But i misunderstood the question and my solution won't work anyway!

Comment: @User112638726 I meant if he symlinks, he cannot keep separate copies, as he wants to.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Yep, he won't, which is why it won't work.